# Authoring in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

I'm brand new to Magento, so bear with me. Let's say I built a module in Magento that houses an image and some text, and I wanted to include that module 3 times on a specific page. How would I add authoring capabilities to allow an author to put a different image and text inside each module?

Comment: What do you mean by a module? From this brief description it seems more likely you want to create some repeatable element. In that case you need to familiarize yourself with the concept of blocks in magento.

Comment: Yes. I do mean a block. From what I understand, you register blocks in the `etc` folder under `modules`, so that's why I referenced it as a module.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read a little bit about the structure of magento 1.x. A good place to start is Alan Storm's blog, especially: http://alanstorm.com/category/magento/#magento-for-php-developers
First 3 posts in that section should get you started on how to prepare a repetable element on frontend.

If you want to jump directly to magento2 I would recommend reading these posts: http://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/#magento-2-mvc

For Magento2 you should also check magento docs: http://devdocs.magento.com/

There are also on-demand video curses from magento itself but they are paid:
magento 1.x: https://u.magento.com/fundamentals-of-magento-1-x-development

magento2: https://u.magento.com/fundamentals-of-magento-2-development

I watched and learned from magento 1.x fundamentals and can recommend it but I haven't seen 2 yet so I am not sure about them.

Comment: While I appreciate all the resources you supplied, is there anything in there specifically that had to do with authoring? That is my question.

Comment: You need to be more specific in what you want to achieve. "Let's say I built a module..." is extremely vague. Describe what you actually want to do (what kind of element you want to build and on which pages to include) and on which platform (magento 1.x or magento 2) and show what you got so far so someone could point you what is missing or required. Depending on those requirements different solutions are possible. Asking "how to build X?" and expecting ready to copy solution is not a best approach.

Comment: "Let's say I build a module" is the first part of my question. The details follow. In this example, my module is just a block that houses an image and some text. If I want to use this module on a given page 3 times, but I want a different image and text per module, what should I look into? I need, I'm assuming, to extend the admin area, where an author could log in, update the images and text per module instance. I don't know how to be more descriptive than this, which is basically a repeat of my OP.

Comment: @Brent everything depends on what exactly you want to do. You can make a widget as it provides a way to define configuration that can be used to render the content but it has some limitations on the way it is added to the page. You can create regular block and in the block class prepare methods to set what you need and correct data provide with layout xml file or directly at parent block. You can create configuration in system.xml.